# Microsoft Visual Studio (2008) - Filters in the Solution Explorer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, solution-explorer

In the Solution Explorer when working with C++ projects there is the standard filters of Header Files, Resource Files, and Source Files. What I'm wanting to accomplish is essentially Filters by folder.

---

Lets say the structure of the files was like this:

- ../Folder1/Source1.cpp
- ../Folder1/Header1.h
- ../Folder1/Source2.cpp
- ../Folder1/Header2.h
- ../AnotherFolder/Source1.cpp
- ../AnotherFolder/Header1.h
- ../AnotherFolder/Source2.cpp
- ../AnotherFolder/Header2.h
- ../SomeOtherSource.cpp

In the Solution Explorer, it would look like:

- Header Files/Header1.h
- Header Files/Header1.h
- Header Files/Header2.h
- Header Files/Header2.h
- Source Files/SomeOtherSource.cpp
- Source Files/Source1.cpp
- Source Files/Source1.cpp
- Source Files/Source2.cpp
- Source Files/Source2.cpp

And I would like to have it look like this:

- Header Files/AnotherFolder/Header1.h
- Header Files/AnotherFolder/Header2.h
- Header Files/Folder1/Header1.h
- Header Files/Folder1/Header2.h
- Source Files/AnotherFolder/Source1.cpp
- Source Files/AnotherFolder/Source2.cpp
- Source Files/Folder1/Source1.cpp
- Source Files/Folder1/Source2.cpp
- Source Files/SomeOtherSource.cpp

---

How would this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to manually create folders yourself and move the files around. I agree this is a much more convenient way to arrange files but AFAIK there is no way to make VS do this automatically.

Comment: But, when you create a filter it doesn't create a folder. So, when moving files into it, you would have to also make the folder, and move the file into that folder as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the Visual Studio Plugin to do this.
I am not sure how you can access "Solution Explorer" programatically.

Answer (score 1):

show all files?

Answer (score 0):

The only method I have found for doing this is completely manual. I have created a hierarchy of filters to match the folders. Then, I move to the "Show All File" view, and select a single folder. I add all files from that folder that are not in my solution to the solution. Then I leave "Show All Files.

At this point, VS does not seem to properly update my list of files. So I need to "Close Solution" and re-open the solution. At this point, the new files are in the solution, but not in a filter. They are in the top level, at the bottom of the project. At which point I drag them into the correct filter.

This is tedious, error-prone, and a waste of time. But since my project is built using an external make system, it's the only way I can keep the project reasonably up-to-date and still get decent search and browse behavior in Visual Studio. The time cost pays itself back in productivity later, but I still begrudge it.